# firebase function af.database.object unable to return each object in a variable

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I want get the user profile data from firebase of a specified user.
By instance I want return the displayName and the email address of the user where UID HBJKD12345

I use this function :

```
this.userProfile = this.af.database.object('/users/'+this.authInfo.uid)
```

But with a `console.log(this.userProfile.email)` I get a "Undefined"

In my view I have to use : `{{(userProfile | async )?.email}}`
With this line I can show the email address of the user but why I get "Undefined" when I try with console.log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view works because of `async`.  It unwraps the actual value.  For `console.log()`, you would need to do something similar.  Try `this.userProfile.$value()`.

Take a look at https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#meta-fields-on-the-object or https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#meta-fields-on-the-object